# Can't install Ubuntu 17.10 due to Optimus graphics

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 17.10, nvidia-optimus

I've tried to install ubuntu 17.10 in my optimus latops, 
i7-6700K, Nvidia 970M and some others specs no relevants IMO.

When I try to run it from usb it **stuck** on the ubuntu logo and won't boot. 
After that edited the grub boot options and added nomodeset.

That way boots and reach the interface but doesn't run **any** app, not the installer not the web browser.

I'd try lots of *workarounds* like nvidia-drm.modeset=1 (or something like that), nouveau.modeset=0 and so on...
I haven't the SO installed (I'm trying to) so I can't install nvidia-current nor bumblebee at boot time.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is incoherent - no offence ...
First you say you can't get the livecd to boot ... then you say you can't install nvidia-current or bumblebee of course you can't - You need the OS first - so let's start there and not get ahead of ourselves.

I assume you have already had an Ubuntu on your Laptop - otherwise how can you have grub??????

So let me tell you Ubuntu 17.10 installs fine (my rig HP Omen I7 Nvidia 960M.

First, forget about grub as it is from your old OS and has NOTHING to do with your new OS (17.10) - it installs last!

Second, if you ARE getting to grub, then your are not booting into the usb stick! and that's your problem.

Go to BIOS settings / Boot Options / and put ??USB HDD?? up to first in the boot order or better yet, go to Boot Devices and Choose it.

Trying to help, Mark
call me 778-251-6177 for any further help